# Checking if a List of Lists contains a certain String

Tags: java, list

I have made a list of Countries based on Name, Population, Surface etc. I have used the Arrays.asList Methods to add each entry. After that, all entries were added to a new list based on continents.
E.g

`List<String> countriesAfrica = Arrays.asList("Nigeria", "Ethiopia", etc)` are added to `List<Africa> africaList = new ArrayList<>();` using a for loop

```
for (int k = 0; k< countriesAfrica.size(); k++) {
        africaList.add(new Africa(countriesAfrica.get(k), 
                              populationAfrica.get(k),
                              surfaceAfrica.get(k), 
                              fertilityAfrica.get(k)));
}
```

In order to search by Country Name, I have tried using the contains() method. I have added the country Africa to a List of Lists, as follows:

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < africaList.size(); j++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            l.add(africaList.get(j).getName());
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            l.add(String.valueOf(africaList.get(j).getSurface()));
        }
    }
    list.add(l);
}
```

Using the contains Method, `list.contains("Nigeria");` returns nothing or false when using SOUT. Any ideas where I did wrong?

Comment: You got a list of lists, you will need to iterate through List and look into each sublist

Comment: Please show your classes and data structures and provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  Also show expected output.

Comment: Should your class really be called `Africa` ? Wouldn't `Country` with an atrribute `continentName` be more appropriate for it? And what is the point of creating a list of lists and adding two different atrribute values instead of directly accesing the desired data?

Comment: `list.contains("Nigeria")` won't work. The `contains (Object o)` method of `List` will search `list` looking to satisfy the condition `e.equals (o)`, where `e` is an element in the `List`. "Nigeria"  is a `String`, so will never equal an `Object` of type `List`. As the comment from @Jonxag said, you need to iterate through `list` and check each sublist.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

#### Original Answer

Your new list has reordered the objects with a list of names, a list of populations, a list of surfaces, and a list of fertility.  This means the first element in the list, at index zero, will always contain a list of countries.  Therefore, you should retrieve that list, and check it for `.contains`

`System.out.println(list.get(0).contains("Nigeria"));`

#### Edit for more clarification and `java.util.stream`

It looks like you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the `contains` method works.  The method is not recursive.  So, when you use `contains` on a list of lists, you can only check to see if the parent list contains a child list.  Take for example the following code:

```java
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> places = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> things = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> everything = new ArrayList<>();

names.add("Bob");
names.add("Steve");
places.add("California");
places.add("New York");
things.add("Watch");
things.add("cars");

everything.add(names);
everything.add(places);
everything.add(things);
```

If I want to check my everything list to see if it contains the `places` list, I can simply check it with the contains method.

```java
boolean containsList = everything.contains(places);
```

this returns `true`.

However, `boolean containsList = everything.contains(places.get(0))` returns false.  In fact, my IDE gives me a warning:

> `List<List<String>>` may not contain objects of type `String`

So, what if I want to check for the presence of "Bob"?  As the person who wrote this line of code, I know that Bob is the first element added to the list.  Since Lists are ordered, I also know that Bob will always be located somewhere in the `0` index of my list.  So, I can simply check if it exists in that index by using the contains method on the index itself.

```java
boolean containsBob = everything.get(0).contains("Bob");
```

This also returns `true`.

But what if I don't know where in the list something exists at?  What if it could be in any index?  This is where streams come in.

```java
boolean caExists = everything.stream().anyMatch(list -> list.contains("California"));
```

This returns true as well.  The difference in this and the previous method, which uses a known index, is that the stream will iterate through the lists contained within `everything` and run the `list.contains()` method on that list`.  Than, if any of the lists return` true`, the result will be` true`.

#### Demonstration

You can see this demonstrated more effectively here:

```java
boolean bobExists = everything.get(0).contains("Bob");
boolean caExists = everything.stream().anyMatch(list -> list.contains("California"));
boolean nothingExists = everything.stream().anyMatch(list -> list.contains("nothing"));
boolean containsList = everything.contains(places);
boolean invalidCheck = everything.contains("Bob");

System.out.println("Contains Bob: " + bobExists);
System.out.println("Contains California: " + caExists);
System.out.println("Contains nothing: " + nothingExists);
System.out.println("Contains the places list: " + containsList);
System.out.println("Invalid check of String to List: " + invalidCheck);
```

The `bobExists` boolean uses a known index to check the existence of a known String.
The next two variables use stream to check the entire parent list.
The `containsList` checks the existence of a child list.
The `invalidCheck` checks the existence of a String in the parent list.   Since the parent list can only contain a list of type String, this will always return false.

The resulting output from running the above code is as follows:

```
Contains Bob: true
Contains California: true
Contains nothing: false
Contains the places list: true
Invalid check of String to List: false
```

As you can see, the stream works to check the existence of a string in the child objects, regardless of location.  This is the most versatile approach.

I hope this helps clarify things.

Comment: Yeah, that was the solution, but I thought as a general rule, it will search throughout the whole content of the List<List>. Your solution makes sense, and it works as per my requirements. I guess I was searching for apples when I had apple juice already made. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide better examples of the different methods for getting the  contents of a child list from the parent.  I hope this helps with your understanding a bit better.